# Mathematica code for q-Stirling numbers

Tags: special-functions, combinatorics, number-theory, partitions, sets

In the paper [*A new $q$-Analog of Stirling Numbers*],(https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01372920/document)[PDF] J. Cigler defined $q$-Stirling numbers of the second
kind as the following:

He considered the weight $w(\pi)$ for each partition $\pi$ of the set $A=\{0,\cdots,n-1\}$, and distinguished the part containing the zero element and called it $B_0$. Then,

$$w(\pi)=q^{\sum_{i\in B_0} i}$$
For each set $A$ of partitions, let $w(A)=\sum _{\pi\in A}w(\pi)$. Also, he considered $A_{n,k}$ to be the set of all partitions of $\{0,\cdots,n-1\}$ into $k$ non-empty parts. So
$${n\brace k}=w(A_{n,k})$$

My question is:

What Mathematica code would generate these Stirling numbers of the second kind?

Comment: At least for the usual Stirling numbers of the second kind, Mathematica has these implemented as ```StirlingS2```, see [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StirlingS2.html)

Comment: Yes, I know it. Also Mathematica has a code fo q-binomial

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: @Hausdorff Thank you so much. But , you write this code based on definition of Matthieu Josuat-Verges paper. our definition for my new problems is according to the Cigler definition.  It is possible write the Mathematica code of q-stirling numbers according Ciqler definitions? Thanks in advance

Comment: @d.y I don't understand, what are you trying to achieve by using the specific construction you give in your question?

Answer (score 7):

On second thought, it is much more convenient to use Theorem 4.5 of the paper as a definition, so

```
A[n_, k_, i_, j_] := Binomial[n, k + i] Binomial[n, k - j] - 
  Binomial[n, k + i + 1] Binomial[n, k - j - 1];

QStirlingS2Fast[n_, k_, q_] := 
  1/(1 - q)^(n - k) Sum[(-1)^i*
  A[n, k, i, j] q^Binomial[j + 1, 2] QBinomial[i, j, q], 
  {j, 0,k}, {i, j, n - k}];
```

This is of course much faster than the implementation via partitions

```
QStirlingS2[10, 5, 3] // RepeatedTiming
(* {2.00612, 3421737} *)

QStirlingS2Fast[10, 5, 3] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.000111509, 3421737} *)
```

and works for large inputs as well

```
QStirlingS2Fast[1000, 20, 3] // N // RepeatedTiming  
(* {0.8409685, 1.465117*^8966} *)
```

**Original post**

Here is one possible implementation, which is a bit brute force. I am using `` Combinatorica` ``  to obtain the set partitions, as well as the definition of the q-Stirling number of the second kind via the number of partition crossings $cr(\pi)$ given in the linked paper.

```
<< Combinatorica`

cr[pi_] := Cases[
  Flatten[
    Tuples /@ Map[
      Partition[#, 2, 1] &, 
      Subsets[Replace[pi, {_} :> Nothing, 1], {2}], 
    {2}], 
  1],
  {{i_, j_}, {k_, l_}} /; i < k < j < l || k < i < l < j
];


QStirlingS2[n_, k_, q_] := Sum[q^Length@cr[pi], {pi, KSetPartitions[Range@n, k]}]
```

This has the behavior for $q\to0$ given in eq.$(13)$,

```
Narayana[n_, k_] := 1/n*Binomial[n, k - 1] Binomial[n, k];
{ QStirlingS2[10, 4, q] /. q -> 0, Narayana[10, 4] }
(* {2520, 2520} *)
```

and also satisfies the identity of Theorem 4.5 in your reference

```
A[n_, k_, i_, j_] := Binomial[n, k + i] Binomial[n, k - j] - 
  Binomial[n, k + i + 1] Binomial[n, k - j - 1];

Theorem45[n_, k_, q_] := 
{
  QStirlingS2[n, k, q] (1 - q)^(n - k),
  Sum[(-1)^i*A[n, k, i, j] q^Binomial[j + 1, 2] QBinomial[i, j, q], 
  {j, 0, k}, {i, j, n - k}] 
}

Theorem45[6, 2, 3]
(* {1872, 1872} *)
```