# Can you give a faster implementation with Mathematica for these q-analog functions?

Tags: special-functions, combinatorics

Now(2023), Mathematica has some QFunctions for q-anlaog. See [Official Documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/QFunctions.html). e.g.:

- `QPochhammer`
- `QFactorial`
- `QBinomial`
- `QGamma`
- `QHypergeometricPFQ`
- `QPolyGamma`

I found [one post about how to implement q-StirlingS2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/262179/mathematica-code-for-q-stirling-numbers)

```
A[n_, k_, i_, j_] := 
  Binomial[n, k + i] Binomial[n, k - j] - 
   Binomial[n, k + i + 1] Binomial[n, k - j - 1];
QStirlingS2Fast[n_, k_, q_] := 
  1/(1 - q)^(n - k) Sum[(-1)^i*
     A[n, k, i, j] q^Binomial[j + 1, 2] QBinomial[i, j, q], {j, 0, 
     k}, {i, j, n - k}];
QStirlingS2Fast[5, 3, q] // FunctionExpand // Expand
```

Imitating the code, I implemented q-StirlingS1

```
B[n_, k_, i_, j_] := 
  Binomial[n + j - 1, k - 1] Binomial[n - i - 1, k - 1] - 
   Binomial[n + j, k - 1] Binomial[n - i - 2, k - 1];

QStirlingS1Fast[n_, k_, q_] := 
  1/((1 - q)^(n - k))*
   Sum[(-1)^j*B[n, k, i, j]*q^Binomial[j + 1, 2]*
     QBinomial[i, j, q], {j, 0, n - k}, {i, j, n - k}];
QStirlingS1Fast[5, 3, q] // FunctionExpand // Expand
```

---

My question is:

**In addition to these, can you give some practical QFunctions and corresponding Mathematica implementations?
Can you give a faster implementation with Mathematica?**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15):

There are [lots of QFunctions](https://www.symmetricfunctions.com/q-analogues.htm) (see also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_q-analogs))

Some are the q(,t)-analog version of the original MATH objects. (orthogonal polynomials, special functions, etc. ) However, it seems to me that some of these are nothing more than terms created to generalize some concepts. Even, for the q-expotential, academics can not standardize the notation.

Some can also be used in q(,t)-analog technique for enumerative combinatorics. On one hand, $q,t$ are just formal variables. On the other hand, it looks like the introducing of these notations can transform the formula shorter. **I'm focusing on these.**

[TOC]

## The MacMahon q-analog of the Catalan numbers

```
Q[n_] := (1 - q^n)/(1 - q);
QMacMahonCatalan[n_, q_] := QBinomial[2 n, n, q]/Q[n + 1];
QMacMahonCatalan[3, q] // FunctionExpand // Expand
```

## The Carlitz and Riordan q-analog of the Catalan numbers

```
QCarlitzAndRiordanCatalan[0] := 1;
QCarlitzAndRiordanCatalan[1] := 1;
QCarlitzAndRiordanCatalan[n_] := 
  Sum[QCarlitzAndRiordanCatalan[k]*
    QCarlitzAndRiordanCatalan[n - 1 - k]*q^(k), {k, 0, n - 1}];
QCarlitzAndRiordanCatalan /@ Range[0, 5] // Expand
```

## The Carlitz q-analog of the Catalan numbers

```
QCarlitzCatalan[0] := 1;
QCarlitzCatalan[1] := 1;
QCarlitzCatalan[n_] := 
  Sum[QCarlitzCatalan[k]*QCarlitzCatalan[n - 1 - k]*
    q^((k + 1) (n - 1 - k)), {k, 0, n - 1}];
QCarlitzCatalan /@ Range[0, 5] // Expand
```

## The q-analog of Fuß–Catalan numbers

```
Q[n_] := (1 - q^n)/(1 - q);
QFußCatalan[n_, m_, q_] := QBinomial[(m + 1) n, n - 1, q]/Q[n];
QFußCatalan[2, 3, q] // FunctionExpand // Expand
```

## The rational Catalan numbers

```
Q[n_] := (1 - q^n)/(1 - q);
RationalCatalan[a_, b_, q_] := QBinomial[a + b, a, q]/Q[a + b];
RationalCatalan[2, 3, q] // FunctionExpand // Expand
```

## the q,t-Catalan numbers

It descibes the distribution:

$$
C_n(q,t)=\sum_{\pi \in L_{n, n}^{+}} q^{\operatorname{area}(\pi)} t^{\text {bounce }(\pi)}
$$

I'd like to use this formula:

$$
C_n(q,t)=
\sum_{b=1}^n \sum_{\substack{\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\ldots+\alpha_b=n \\
\alpha_i>0}} t^{\alpha_2+2 \alpha_3+\ldots+(b-1) \alpha_b} q^{\sum_{i=1}^b\left(\begin{array}{c}
\alpha_i \\
2
\end{array}\right)} \prod\limits_{i=1}^{b-1}\left[\begin{array}{c}
\alpha_i+\alpha_{i+1}-1 \\
\alpha_{i+1}
\end{array}\right]
$$

```
QTCatalan[n_, q_, t_] := 
 Module[{CalculateTerm}, 
  CalculateTerm[avec_List] := Module[{part1, part2, part3, b},
    b = Length[avec];
    part1 = t^Sum[(i - 1)*avec[[i]], {i, 2, b - 1}];
    part2 = q^Sum[Binomial[avec[[i]], 2], {i , 1, b}];
    part3 = 
     Product[QBinomial[avec[[i]] + avec[[i + 1]] - 1, avec[[i + 1]], 
       q], {i, 1, b - 1}];
    part1*part2*part3
    ];
  Sum[Sum[
    CalculateTerm[avec], {avec, 
     FrobeniusSolve[Array[1 &, b], n]}], {b, 1, n}]
  ]

QTCatalan[#, q, t] &    /@ Range[1, 3] // FunctionExpand // Expand
```

## q,t-Narayana numbers

It describes the distribution:

$$
N(n;q,t)=\sum_{w \in D P(n)} q^{\mathrm{maj}(w)} t^{\text {peaks }(w)}
$$

Where we sum over all Dyck paths.

I'd like to use the formula:

$$
N(n,k;q)
=
\frac{q^{k(k-1)}}{[n]_q}\left[\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right]_q\left[\begin{array}{c}
n \\
k-1
\end{array}\right]_q
$$

$$
N(n;q,t)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} t^k N(n,k;q)
$$

```
Q[n_] := (1 - q^n)/(1 - q);
QNarayana[n_, k_, q_] := 
  QBinomial[n, k, q]*QBinomial[n, k - 1, q]*q^(k (k - 1))/Q[n];
QNarayana[3, 2, q] // FunctionExpand // Expand


QTNarayana[n_, q_, t_] := Sum[t^k*QNarayana[n, k, q], {k, 1, n}]
QTNarayana[3, q, t] // FunctionExpand // Expand
```

## q-Multinomial

It describes the distribution:

$$
\left[\begin{array}{c}
m_1+m_2+\cdots+m_r \\
m_1, m_2, \ldots, m_r
\end{array}\right]=\sum_{w \in R(\mathbf{m})} q^{\operatorname{maj} w}
$$

Where we sum over all the words of length $m=m_1+m_2+\cdots + m_r$ which are *rearrangments* of the nondecreasing word $1^{m_1} 2^{m_2} \cdots r^{m_r}$
(i.e. the number of character $1$ is $m_1$, the number of character $2$ is $m_2$, $\cdots$)

```
QMultinomial[mlist_List, q_] := 
 QPochhammer[q, q, Total@mlist]/
  Product[QPochhammer[q, q, mi], {mi, mlist}]
QMultinomialDefinition2[mlist_List, q_] := 
 QFactorial[Total@mlist, q]/Product[QFactorial[mi, q], {mi, mlist}]



QMultinomial[{1, 2, 3}, q] // FunctionExpand // Expand
Limit[%, q -> 1]
Multinomial[1, 2, 3]
```

## The Euler-Mahonian polynomial $A_{\mathbf{m}}(t, q)$

I'd like to use the formula:

$$
\frac{1}{(t ; q)_{m+1}} A_{\mathbf{m}}(t, q)=\sum_{s \geq 0} t^s\left[\begin{array}{c}
m_1+s \\
s
\end{array}\right] \ldots\left[\begin{array}{c}
m_r+s \\
s
\end{array}\right]
$$

```
EulerMahonianPolynomial[mlist_List, t_, q_] := 
 QPochhammer[t, q, Length[mlist]+1 ]*
  Sum[t^s*Product[QBinomial[mi + s, s, q], {mi, mlist}], {s, 0, 
    Infinity}]
  
EulerMahonianPolynomialLimitedVersion[mlist_List, t_, q_] := 
 QPochhammer[t, q, Length[mlist]+1 ]*
  Sum[t^s*Product[QBinomial[mi + s, s, q], {mi, mlist}], {s, 0, 8}]

EulerMahonianPolynomialLimitedVersion[{1, 2, 3}, t, q] // FunctionExpand // 
  FullSimplify // Expand
```

## the q-maj-Eulerian polynomial ${}^{\operatorname{maj}} A_r (t,q)$

When the multi-index $\mathbf{m}$ is of the form $(1^r)=(1,1,\cdots,1)$, the Euler-Mahonian polynomial $A_{\mathbf{m}}(t, q)$ will be denoted by ${}^{\operatorname{maj}} A_r (t,q)$ and referred to as the *q-maj-Eulerian polynomial*.

```
QMajEulerianPolynomial[r_, t_, q_] := 
 EulerMahonianPolynomial[Array[1 &, r], t, q]
```

## ...

---

## Reference

[THE q-SERIES IN COMBINATORICS; PERMUTATION STATISTICS](https://irma.math.unistra.fr/%7Eguoniu/papers/p56lectnotes2.pdf)

[The q, t-Catalan Numbers and the Space of Diagonal Harmonics](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ejhaglund/books/qtcat.pdf)

Comment: Wow ,useful Things. +1)

Answer (score 2):

I have some of these implemented in my CombinatoricTools.m package; [see my GitHub page](https://github.com/PerAlexandersson/Mathematica-packages/blob/master/CombinatoricTools.m).

```
qInteger;
qFactorial;
qBinomial;
qMultinomial;
qHookFormula;
qCatalan;
qCarlitzCatalan;
qtCatalan;
qNarayana;
qKreweras;
```

I had forgotten that I had the qt-Catalans implemented, but this is the code from the above mentioned package. I suspect this recursive formula is faster than the one mentioned in a different answer (it is apparently Thm. 3.4 from Jim's book).

```
qBinomial[n_Integer,k_Integer,q_:1]:=qBinomial[n,k,q]=FunctionExpand[QBinomial[n,k,q]];

(* This recursion is basically thm 3.4 in Jims book *)
qtH[n_, n_, q_, t_] := q^Binomial[n, 2];
qtH[n_, k_, q_, t_] := 
  qtH[n, k, q, t] = t^(n - k) q^Binomial[k, 2] Sum[
     qBinomial[r + k - 1, r, q] qtH[n - k, r, q, t], {r, n - k}];
qtCatalan::usage = "qtCatalan[n,q,t] is the qt-Catalan polynomial.";
qtCatalan[n_Integer, q_: 1, t_: 1] := Together[qtH[n + 1, 1, q, t]/t^n];
```

In general, I found it useful to define this FunctionExpanded qbinomial version and memoize it for speed.